# Ajax function within ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to write a live update shopping cart. I've tried to run one function inside the other, but can only get it to work on reload. What is wrong in my approach here?

EDIT: I've now edited from checkKart to checkKart();

```
$(function checkKart() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",

            url: "checkCart.php",
            success: function(html) {

                $("#handlevogn").html(html);
           }

        });
});

function addToCart(product_name, design_name, price, qty) {
     $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: 'test.php',
             data: {qty: qty, product_name: product_name, design_name: design_name, price: price},
             success: function(data) {
                  alert("Varen er i handlekurven");
                  checkKart();
             }
           });
    return "Varen er i handlekurven";

}
```

Comment: tried with checkKart();  ?

Comment: As for the first function, you should consider `$().load()`. As for the second function, perhaps you should actually call he `checkKart` function from within the callback.

Comment: Ok. I realize I'm in a bit too deep here. I'll read up on .load() and try again. :)

Comment: Under you `alert`, you need to actually call the function.  `checkKart();`

Comment: Just wanted to add, this is no commercial project. I am just trying to learn more about ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkKart() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "checkCart.php",
        success: function(html) {
            $("#handlevogn").html(html);
        }
    });
};

function addToCart(product_name, design_name, price, qty) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {qty: qty, product_name: product_name, design_name: design_name, price: price},
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Varen er i handlekurven");
            checkKart();
         }
    });

    return "Varen er i handlekurven";
}
```

That should work.

not sure why you had your first function wrapped inside of $(). if you were trying to write a jQuery plugin the proper syntax is this:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

  };
})( jQuery );
```

which you can read more about here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to get a grip on the syntax. This was a great lesson! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error console *should* be telling you that `checkKart` is an undefined function, the reason being that as written:

```
$(function checkKart() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
});
```

what you've created is a "named function expression", in which the name is only visible *within* that function, and the name is not exported to the enclosing scope.

If you define the function normally without the `$(...)` wrapper, everything should work.

Comment: sorry but I thought named function expression's were like this: `(function(){})()` not like this: `$(...)`? my reference: [link](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#named-expr)

Comment: @DeckerWBrower The `$(...)` is a jQueryism that _calls_ the (named) function expression that has been passed to it (the `...`) when the DOM is ready.